# Getting, (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist error

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When i am trying to get data from facebook using graph api, i am getting this error,

```
{"error":
{"message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 124186682456_10151302011177457&access_token=REMOVED_ACCESS_TOKEN",
"type":"OAuthException",
"code":803}}
```

Can anyone help me in how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 10):

If that is an accurate representation of the error you're receiving, you're incorrectly appending the access token after a `&` character instead of a `?`.
You need to use `?` for the start of the query string, and `&` to separate the parameters inside the query string

e.g. 
`https://graph.facebook.com/124186682456_10151302011177457?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: In my case, the error was : "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 4oh4.php",   and was due to not appending "act_" in front of the account number (parent_id='act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>'). You might want to check that.

Answer (score 1):

Placement of access_token parameter immediately after `?` has nothing to do with issue...

It could be that your URL is littered with `%20` or similar stuff.

I got this error when trying a test example from [Facebook API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/web/search#example), at first I have read highest voted answer, but moving `access_token` parameter immediately after `?`  didn't work, I then inspected URL more closely and found some of encoded spaces `%20` that were stuck to parameter `fields` and some others, removing which fixed the issue.

try following URL (just replace access_token parameter with yours)

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&fields=name,checkins,picture&q=cafe&center=40.7304,-73.9921&distance=1000&access_token=[YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]

If it works look for problem in Facebook parameter names

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: FYI, this has now been deprecated. {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#12) Place Search API is deprecated for third parties effective v8.0 is deprecated for versions v8.0 and higher",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 12,
      "fbtrace_id": "xxx"
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

This was happening for me with the Instagram content publishing API which also rides off the facebook graph api. It seems to happen when something is wrong with the API URL you are trying to send to Facebook via GET request.

In my case, something was happening in my code causing the `user_id` and `access_token` to not be passed to the URL before trying to query the graph API.